# Import statement has no intellisense

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6.3

I have upgrade the XCode to 6.3 and it seems the intellisense not work, so when I type import and it don't popup the related libraries. Is it normal?

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it will help to delete the *derived data* folder of your project and compile everything new.

Comment: Didn't work for me, the only thing that works is what @j.f. below writes: typing two quotes...

Answer (score 2):

I've found that Xcode seems to need both quotation marks now. I used to always type out my import statements like so. At least I'm pretty sure I did...

```
#import "headerFileNa...
```

and now this happens:

[image: ScreenShot1]

But if you either click enter or tab to get within the quotation marks, the intellisense works. Or if you just simply type the two quotation marks your self.

[image: ScreenShot2]

Answer (score 0):

I you work with Swift, it's still a bit buggy, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Most of the time it's just for 1 or 2 min, or until you reboot XCode.